# Find hostapd's access point SSID

Tags: networking, wifi, access-point

I have a Linux machine operating as an access point using hostapd and dnsmasq. The AP is working fine (the device is `wlan0`), but I am having difficulty finding the SSID of the AP for monitoring purposes. I am really using the nl80211 Netlink interface, but `iw` is a useful proxy here.

The output of `iw dev wlan0 link` is:

```
Interface wlan0
    ifindex 2
    type AP
    wiphy 3
```

And `iw dev wlan0 link` is:

```
Not connected.
```

However, I'd like to find out the SSID of the running AP on this device (without having to ask the program that set it up in the first place).

Comment: Does `iwlist wlan0 scan` also not show it?

Comment: Also can you not just get the SSID from the configuration file for hostapd? http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd

Comment: @slm Afraid not: `iwlist wlan0 scan` gives `wlan0   no scan results`. I could look in `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`, and that will be my fallback, I was just hoping for a more direct method, since then I would also have to make sure hostapd is running OK.

Comment: I'll keep looking. I was wondering if hostapd had any cli i/f for querying into it. I've not used it but if it was installed using a pkg mgr app you might want to poke into what was installed with it.

Comment: @Inductiveload Did you find a way to query the active SSID? I have the same issue and it looks like iw does not manage the AP. I tried running iwevent and no events show up if a user connects to the AP.